# Can't marshal byteplay code object?

Tags: python

I have the following code. I'm compiling code with byteplay and the code compiles, `dis.dis(c)` works just fine, but `marshal.dump()` errors out with:

```
ValueError: unmarshallable object
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
code.append((RETURN_VALUE, None))
c = Code(code, [], [], False, False, False, str(Symbol.intern(self.getNS().__name__, "<string>")), "<str>", 0, None)
import marshal
import pickle
import py_compile
import time
import dis

dis.dis(c)
codeobject = c.to_code()

with open('output.pyc', 'wb') as fc:
    fc.write(py_compile.MAGIC)
    py_compile.wr_long(fc, long(time.time()))
    marshal.dump(c, fc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on `byteplay`, but shouldn't that be:

```
codeobject = c.to_code()
...
marshal.dump(codeobject, fc)
```